# javascript - getElementById returns null only for dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, html

If I have only

```
<table id='InputTable'>
</table>
```

and I write in console

```
document.getElementById('InputTable')
```

it returns

```
<table id='InputTable'>
</table>
```

as expected. However, if my HTML is

```
<table id='InputTable'>
</table>
<script type='text/javascript'>
        createInputTable(3,3);
</script>
```

the same command returns `null`. The function createInputTable() is defined as:

```
function createInputTable(row_num, col_num, vals){
        if (typeof vals=='undefined'){
                vals = new Array();
                for (i=0; i<row_num; i++){
                        vals[i] = Array.apply(null, Array(col_num)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0);
                }
        }
        var form = document.createElement('form')
        var old_table = document.getElementById('InputTable')
        var table = document.createElement('table')
        var rows = new Array();
        var cells = new Array();
        for (i=0; i<row_num; i++){
                rows[rows.length] = table.insertRow(i);
                cells[cells.length] = new Array();
                for (j=0; j<col_num; j++){
                        if (typeof vals[i][j]=='undefined') vals[i][j] = 0;
                        cells[i][j] = rows[i].insertCell(j);
                        cells[i][j].innerHTML = '<input type="number" name="'+'a'+i+j+'" step="any" value='+vals[i][j]+' class=input_matrix />';
                }
        }
        old_table.parentNode.replaceChild(table, old_table);
}
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You new table don't have an **`id`**.

**Add**

**`table.id = "InputTable";`**

**after**

**`var table = document.createElement('table');`**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the element refered to as `table` doesn’t have the `id` property with the value `InputTable`. There should be the line

```
table.setAttribute('id','InputTable');
```

or

```
table.id='InputTable';
```

after

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
```